# Position a div relative to browser size either above or below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

Ladies and Gentlemen. I have a `#quicklook` div.

```
#quicklook{
    height: 500px;
    width: 400px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:15px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #BEBEBE;
    color:#000;
    z-index:100;
    display:none;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','.quicklook-link',function(){
    var quicklookLink = $(this);                
    quicklooktimerShow = setTimeout(function(){     
        createQuickLook(quicklookLink);

          //some ajax request to load content in '#quicklook'   
        },3000);

}).on('mouseleave','.quicklook-link',function(){

            clearTimeout(quicklooktimerShow);
            removeQuickLook();   

});





    function createQuickLook(div){
        removeQuickLook();
        $('<div>',{
            id:'quicklook'
        }).append($('<div>',{ id:"quicklook-triangle"})).appendTo(div);

            $('#quicklook').show();             


    }
    function removeQuickLook(){
        $('#quicklook').remove();
        $('#quicklook-triangle').remove();
    }
```

Currently when i hover over `.quicklook-link` for more than ***3s***  the `#quicklook` is created

I want Two things to happen.

- When i do `.mouseenter .quicklook-link` if there is not enough space
  below the viewport of screen then position the `#quicklook` above the
  `.quicklook-link` else let it remain below. Just like done in
  **google+**.
- Another bug is there as soon as mouse is left from `.quicklook-link`
  the `removeQuickLook()` function is called and `#quicklook` is
  hidden. But i want few seconds say(3-4s) time's delay to hide that
  `#quicklook`.

Answer (score 0):

For the time delay problem, have you tried to implement this?

http://api.jquery.com/delay/